# Change multiple CSS attributes at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to change multiple CSS attributes of an element with one line?

Right now if I have an element and try to change some CSS attributes, then I have to write one line of code for each css attribute. For example:

```js
$("div#start").click(function(){
    $("p#message").css("background-color", "red");
    $("p#message").css("color", "white");
    $("p#message").css("padding", "5px");
    $("p#message").css("width", "120px");
    $("p#message").css("text-align", "center");
});
```

```css
div#start {
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

div#start:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #A1A1A1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="message">Hi Folks</p>
<div id="start">Change CSS</div>
```

As you can see in my example above, I am writing one line for each CSS attribute. Is is possible to accomplish this with a single command? For example something like this:

```
$("p#message").css(
    "background-color": "red",
    "color": "white",
    "padding": "5px",
    "width": "120px",
    "text-align": "center"
);
```

Comment: It's **well worth your time** to review [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css).

Comment: Your very close, just wrap it in `{...}`.

Comment: 1) RTFM http://api.jquery.com/css 2) don't apply this many styles through JS code. Set them all in classes in an external stylesheet and add/remove those classes as needed

Comment: I don't like the examples in the documentation, they are confusing sometimes. And i was not able to find the part where the multi line css is explained. The docu should be more structured.

Comment: The jQuery doco *is* structured, with a reasonably consistent structure applied to *all* the methods. I find some of the examples rather unhelpful, but if you had read the .css() method's contents section carefully where it shows the different method signatures you'd have seen that one of the options is to pass "properties", and clicking on that would show you that option's full explanation.

Comment: Yes i found it but it took me a while... If it would be structured then it would be very easy to find. If there would be the header "Manipulate multiple attributes" at the top for example, then i wouldn't have to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the object to the `css()`. The code is missing `{` and `}`.

```
$("p#message").css({
    "background-color": "red",
    "color": "white",
    "padding": "5px",
    "width": "120px",
    "text-align": "center"
});
```

As the styles are fixed, i'll suggest to make a CSS class and add the class.

```
$("p#message").addClass('myClass');
```

CSS:

```
.myClass {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an [object as the argument for setting multiple CSS properties](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties).

```
$("p#message").css({
    "background-color":"red",
    "color":"white",
    "padding":"5px",
    "width":"120px",
    "text-align":"center"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write in one line like that :

```
$("p#message").css("background-color","red").css("color","white").css("padding","5px").css("width","120px").css("text-align","center");
```

}

Comment: That is pretty much what the question author was already doing, see other answers for the right solution!